# AngularFire catch background notifications

Tags: angular, firebase, push-notification, angularfire2, angularfire

Is there a any way to catch push notification while angular application is running in Background (second tab)?

I have this function for catch push notifications:

```
  receiveMessage() {
    this.afMessaging.messages.subscribe((payload) => {
      console.log("new message received. ", payload);
      this.currentMessage.next(payload);
    });
  }
```

But it don't fired when application is in background (second tab).

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#handle_messages_when_your_web_app_is_in_the_background

You need to define your service worker. Check the docs for more info.

Answer (score 4):

in firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
});
```

and in ts file insert bind function

```
this.afMessaging.messaging.subscribe(
    (_messaging) => {
        _messaging.onBackgroundMessage = _messaging.onBackgroundMessage.bind(_messaging);        
    });
```

works for me!

Comment: What is `this.afMessaging` ?

Comment: afMessaging is an instance of AngularFireMessaging class imported from @angular/fire/compat/messaging